# Pass opened window instance as parameter into second window

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

For example: I have two windows (A and B). One instance of A is currently opened with a combo-box (loaded with items in a database). I click on the button "Edit" and window B opens allowing me to edit the contents of the mentioned database. What I need is for window A to automatically refresh its content when I press "Save" in window B or when I close window B.

All the code I could think of:

a.cpp

```
b *new_window = new b;
b->show();
b->passwindowfunction(this);
```

b.cpp

```
void b::passwindowfunction(sometypeidkwht window)
{
    window->combobox...
}
```

as for the header files, i dont know what I would declare.

Comment: Why Passing opened window instance as parameter into second window?. I think you need object to object communication, Please go through signal/slot, then update the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals / slots system of Qt provides you with what you need here. You can do something like this: -

```
class QWindowA : public QWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    private slots:
        void RefreshContent(); // refreshes content of the window
};


 class QWindowB : public QWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        void Save(); // save content and emit Saved() signal

    signals:
        void Saved();
};
```

As you can see, WindowA declares a slot function that will get called when it needs to update and WindowB has a signal Saved().

You need to connect the signal of Saved to the slot RefreshContent() :-

```
// Assuming instances winA and winB have been created
connect(winB, &WindowB::Saved, winA, &WindowA::RefreshContent); // using Qt 5 connect call
```

In the Save() function of WindowB, when you've finished saving the content emit the Saved() signal: -

```
emit Saved();
```

Due to the previous connect call, WindowA will update its content.

As for closing the window, if you delete WindowB when it gets closed, just emit the Saved() signal in the destructor of WindowB for WindowA to get updated, else handle the close event: -

```
void WindowB::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    emit Saved();
    QWindow::closeEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very vague what you ask. You could use a QDialog based widget. Open it modal. Then you can query its status when it closes. Regardless if you closed the window, or pressed 'save'.

You could also connect your save button's clicked() signal with a slot in A. But then you have to write extra code for when window B is closed. Overriding the closeEvent of window B. On the signals you'd have to update your QComboBox.

Or, the absolute luxury variant, you use a database aware model for your QComboBox, e.g. based on  QSqlQueryModel. Then your QComboBox updates automatically when you change data in your database.